# How to get array data to render in html templete in Angular ngOnInit

Tags: html, node.js, angular, http, router

I am trying to fetch the info from backend and showing it in Angular components. But I am fetching it in ngOnInit first before rendering but it is showing me error in angular.
This is my component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { UserService } from '../shared/user.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor( private userService: UserService, private router: Router) { }

  userDetails = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService.getUserProfile().subscribe(
      (res:any)=>{
        this.userDetails = res['user'];
      },
      err=>{}
    );
  }

  onLogout(){
    this.userService.deleteToken();
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }

}
```

This is my component.html file

```
<table #ngIf="userDetails" class="table-fill">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2" class="text-center">
                User Profile
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name</td>
            <td>{{userDetails.name}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email</td>
            <td>{{userDetails.email}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" class="text-center">
                <input type="button" (click)="onLogout()" value="Logout">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This is the error I am getting

```
Error: src/app/home/home.component.html:1:15 - error NG8003: No directive found with exportAs 'userDetails'.

1 <table #ngIf="userDetails" class="table-fill">
                ~~~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/home/home.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component HomeComponent.


Error: src/app/home/home.component.html:12:31 - error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never[]'.

12             <td>{{userDetails.name}}</td>
                                 ~~~~

  src/app/home/home.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component HomeComponent.


Error: src/app/home/home.component.html:16:31 - error TS2339: Property 'email' does not exist on type 'never[]'.

16             <td>{{userDetails.email}}</td>
                                 ~~~~~

  src/app/home/home.component.ts:7:16
    7   templateUrl: './home.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component HomeComponent.
```

Help me. I have tried a lot but it is not working

Comment: It should be *ngIf="userDetails" NOT #ngIf="userDetails", replace # with *

Comment: I have replaced it but still its showing me this error  Property 'name' does not exist on type 'never[]' for both name and email

Comment: If you are accessing userDetails.name, that means userDetails is not an array. Then please don't define it as an array, define it userDetails; OR userDetails = ""; 
And check *ngIf="userDetails.name" in html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are accessing userDetails as an Object.So, replace

```
userDetails = [] as userDetails:any;
```